# PHP + Regular Expressions

Tags: php, regex, expression

I'm having a hard time trying to remove duplicated images from an specific text/article.

Let's say that I have an image tag where the src="http://domain.com/image.jpg" and 
I want to remove(/hide) all the images that have the following pattern:

```
http://domain.com/image-999x999.jpg
```

Currently, my regex expression is (and it isn't working):

```
'/'.preg_quote('src="http://domain.com/image-').'([0-9]{3}\x[0-9]{3})\.(gif|png|jpg)/i'
```

(the regex, as an example, should ignore this: http://domain.com/image-20-999x999.jpg)

Any suggestions are more then welcome!

Cheers,

Comment: In what way isn't it working?

Comment: Probably the `\x`, as it should most likely be `x` instead. Either that or the `src="` part...

Comment: (Also enable `error_reporting` whenever something isn't working.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case the [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/preg_quote) isn't working, because you left out the second parameter. It needs to know your used delimiter, else it can't escape it:

```
 preg_quote('src="http://domain.com/image-', '/')
```

Preferrably you could use another delimiter for the regex itself however. Like `#` that isn't present in your base href. And you don't actually need the quoting if it's just that fixed string.

Comment: Thank you Mario, this simple but straight answer solve my problem!
;)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
preg_match_all('/src="http:\/\/domain\.com\/image\-\d{3}xd{3}\.(gif|png|jpg)/'
                inputHTML, $imgs);
```

I haven't tried this yet, I hope it works :)